# How to get value in conditional statement in c# outside of that conditional statement?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

How to get value in conditional statement in c# (example in a if statement and you want the value in the if statement be used outside it ) how?

example

```
int a, b, c;
if (a > 3)
{
    c = 20;
}
else if (b < 3)
{
    c = 10;
}  

//how do i get the value of c outside the conditional statement??
Console.WriteLine("{0}", c);

//it always says local variable unassigned local variable
```

*update supposedly my code is correct and i
ve declared a; and i want to use the value of a outside the conditional statement.
*update all i want to know is to get the value of c outside the conditional

Comment: Where is `a` declared?

Comment: `a = a++` wouldn't compile if you haven't assigned a value to `a`. `Console.WriteLine("{0}", a);` wouldn't be the line to error out;

Comment: You may know "this condition is true in the only case I care about" but the compiler doesn't; it has to generate code for every path.  So what value should `a` have (and be displayed) when the condition is false?

Answer (score 3):

It seems you declared `a` but didn't initialize it.In `C#` you should initialize *local* variables to something before the first usage. If your `if` statement evaluates to `false` then `a` will remain uninitialized.And even if it would evalute to `true` you are trying to read its value (in `x++`) before initializing it, so it will still be a problem. To fix that just initialize it with a default value while declaring:

```
int a = 0;
```

Comment: If it wasn't initialized, then `a++` would be an error.  I suspect we haven't been given the actual failing code.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `a` should be declared outside the `if` statement. IE

```
int a = 1;

if(condition){
  a=a++;
}

console.WriteLine("{0}",a);
```

However, there are several issues with your code. Most notably, are you sure you want to be doing `a=a++`? This code is redundant, you should be doing just `a++`.

I suspect your real issue lies outside the code you shared. If you post more code I can refine my answer to help you more.

Comment: If `a` wasn't in scope at that point the error would be that `a` hasn't been declared, not that it hasn't been assigned to.

Comment: If you feel that the question is not providing enough information to be answerable then you should be voting/flagging it for closure and helping the author fix it, not posting an answer that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Servy It attempts to answer the question... 99% of it is answering the question. It has one small comment. I do not see an issue.

Comment: Well, it's all wrong.  Your fix doesn't fix the OP's problem, and the problem you assert exists doesn't exist in the OP's code or fit with his description of the problem.  Yes, it *attempts* to answer the question, but it fails miserably.  This is in no small part to problems in the question making a real, quality, correct, answer functionally impossible.

Comment: @Servy you understand me bro T_T i need help

Comment: @KellyDecretales Then you need to provide a complete code sample that accurately reproduces your problem, along with exactly what isn't working with it.  As it is you're not there.

Comment: @Servy I have 1 and its too long. but if you insist.

Answer (score 0):

In your new code example, the problem is that you've declared variables `a`, `b`, and `c` but have not **initialized** them. An if statement might be entered and it might not be entered so any assignments done inside of an if statement might not be executed.

You need to tell the compiler what the initial values of a, b and c are before you can use them, which I think almost everyone here has already been saying. Try changing your code to this:

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
if (a > 3)
{
    c = 20;
}
else if (b < 3)
{
    c = 10;
}  

//This should print out 10
Console.WriteLine("{0}", c);

//no more compile errors will occur
```

Notice that `a`, `b`, and `c` have been given default values of `0` so in the event that the if statement is not entered, they will still be assigned a usable value.

Also, if `a = 0` and `b = 4` then the entire if block is skipped, leaving `c` untouched which is where its default value of `0` will be printed to the console.

Another option, which isn't the best thing to do in my opinion is the following

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c;
if (a > 3)
{
    c = 20;
}
else if (b < 3)
{
    c = 10;
}
else
{
    c = 1;
}

Console.WriteLine("{0}", c);
```

This will compile even though you're not initializing the `c` variable because in a round about way you are; in the final `else` the variable is assigned 1 so there would be no case were `c` is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not `c` at all; your problems are `a` and `b`. You just need a bit more understanding how the compiler works.

Let's put it this way: you have...

```
int a, b, c;
```

Here, you're telling the compiler that it will use 3 variables that somewhere, eventually, will contain `int` values; but now they don't have nothing, they're empty (note: **not 0; empty**) or as known in C#, they're `null`.

When the compiler reaches here:

```
if (a > 3)
{
    c = 20;
}
```

it says: "whoops! I need to check if `a` is less than 3, but before this line `a` is never assigned a value, it's empty, and I can't check it like that. I'll better throw an error."

Same happens with the next condition.

If, as other answers say, before the condition you assign them a value, the compiler will be able to compare and use them.

Now let's take a look at your original code:

```
int a;
//I'll asume you declared a the same way that the other code

if (condition)//this is true
{
    a = a++;
}
//how do i get the value of a?

Console.WriteLine("{0}", a);
//it always says local variable unassigned local variable
```

When the compiler reaches to `Console.WriteLine("{0}", a);`, it says: "Hmmm... I have to print `a`, but it has a value **only if** `condition`is `true`, **but if it is false**, I won't be able to print it because it'll be empty. Better throw an error now than when running!"

As you see, is all about using your variables only after you're sure that all possible ways that lead to your line of code assign a value to that variable.